Cannot add cluster deployed in microk8s on the Reaper UI
I am trying to use reaper to manage my cassandra cluster, so far I am using a bitnami-cassandra and deployed it in microk8s.
The cassandra cluster is fine, and I have 2 pods, nodetool works fine.
When I configured the test_cassandra-reaper.yaml and get it started with this command
REAPER_SYMMETRIC_KEY=$(echo REAPER_SYMMETRIC_KEY) java -jar server/target/cassandra-reaper-3.6.0.jar server resource/test_cassandra-reaper.yaml
I could see this very encouraging logs
WARN   [2024-05-28 15:50:46,944] [main] i.c.ReaperApplication - Reaper is ready to get things done! 
But when I get into the GUI at 'http://localhost:8080/webui', I cannot add any cluster!
So the 'e-5cg2451q42' is my hostname of WSL2, and also the name of my microk8s node.
I tried to replace the seed node with other names in below:

localhost
127.0.0.1
every pod name
bitnami-cassandra-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
bitnami-cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local

But the logs keep the same
caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
ERROR  [2024-05-28 15:57:12,254] [dw-71 - POST /cluster/auth] i.c.r.ClusterResource - failed to find cluster with seed hosts: [e-5cg2451q42] 
io.cassandrareaper.ReaperException: no host could be reached through JMX
        at io.cassandrareaper.management.jmx.JmxManagementConnectionFactory.connectAny(JmxManagementConnectionFactory.java:218)
        at io.cassandrareaper.management.jmx.JmxManagementConnectionFactory.connectAny(JmxManagementConnectionFactory.java:54)
        at io.cassandrareaper.management.ClusterFacade.connectImpl(ClusterFacade.java:897)
        at io.cassandrareaper.management.ClusterFacade.connect(ClusterFacade.java:879)
        at io.cassandrareaper.management.ClusterFacade.getClusterName(ClusterFacade.java:220)
        at io.cassandrareaper.resources.ClusterResource.findClusterWithSeedHost(ClusterResource.java:376)

In the logs, I find this line valuable:
'no host could be reached through JMX'
But I don't find an answer ANYWHERE

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

By default, Cassandra is configured with local JMX access only. You need to make sure that the Cassandra nodes are configured such that remote JMX access is enabled in conf/cassandra-env.sh.
In a Kubernetes environment, you will also need to make sure that the JMX port (default is 7199) are accessible externally on the pods. Repairs are kicked off via JMX which makes remote JMX access to the pods necessary.
In case you weren't aware, K8ssandra is our opinionated deployment of Cassandra on Kubernetes using the k8ssandra-operator with all the admin tools bundled in, pre-configured and ready to use out-of-the-box:

Reaper for automated repairs
Medusa for backups and restores
Metrics Collector for monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana
Traefik templates for k8s cluster ingress
Stargate.io - a data gateway for connecting to Cassandra using REST API, GraphQL API and JSON/Doc API

K8ssandra and all the bundled software components are open-source so is free to use. Cheers!

Hi Erick, thanks for your reply, I will take some time on the k8ssandra after. Due to the project schedules, I may opt command line to do the repair jobs.
